# Gtk has no attribute 'DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT'

Tags: python, pygobject

I am trying to create a working dialog box in Python 2.7/GTK+ 3 (PyGObject). I found an online tutorial which offered the following code...

```
md = Gtk.MessageDialog(window,
        Gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
        Gtk.MESSAGE_INFO,
        Gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE,
        msg)

response = md.run()
```

However, running this results in the error...

> AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute
>   'DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT'

I'm fairly sure this has to do with the fact that the above code worked on PyGtk (GTK 2). How do I get this working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a little bit of research, I found that, yes, this is due to a change in library structure from PyGTK to PyGObject. ([Read the documentation](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html#messagedialog) for how to work with dialogs, and see line 27 of the example at that link's bookmark.)

The enumeration `Gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT` does not appear to exist in PyGObject, as the documentation suggests passing a `0` directly.

Beyond that, `Gtk.MESSAGE_INFO` has been moved to `Gtk.MessageType.INFO`, and `GTK.BUTTONS_CLOSE` has been moved to `Gtk.ButtonsType.CLOSE`.

This may be bright-blazingly obvious to some, but Gtk isn't exactly famous for their documentation, so this is for anyone who might have been fighting with this for a while as I did.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this [Flags](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/flags.html#Gtk.DialogFlags) documentation, there is a `Gtk.DialogFlags.DESTROY_WITH_PARENT` flag available.